# Reading data from ODB while Abaqus calculation is running

Tags: python, abaqus, odb, abaqus-odb

I have a problem with a free-fall object.
I have to extract the coordinates of the position (x,y,z) of the center of mass while the calculation is being solved.

Is it possible to extract the x,y,z coordinate point data from the ODB while the calculation is running via something?

I am considering Python or any other solutions for this task